# 18.04 Problems with bind mounting a folder at bootup

Tags: mount, fstab, bind

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu media PC with a new SSD. Problem is that the SSD does not have enough capacity to store my main media directory so I have kept it on the old 3TB hard drive which is now sdb1 and sdb2. This was my main drive before I upgraded and was running Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I am running a fresh install of 18.04 using the new SSD and if I run the following command in terminal:

```
mount --bind /mnt/88b11020-8c51-42e6-8525-950eaa23d888/home/myusername/Uncompressed1music Uncompressed\ music
```

When I do this, the system works as I would have expected and all my Uncompressed music files on my old 3TB drive can then be accessed through the new folder named "home/Uncompressed music" on my new SSD, sda1. (I have changed my own username for the generic term, "myusername" as well as the actual the hard drive designator.)

My problem is that I want to make this happen at every boot up and this is where I experiencing difficulty and asking those who have more Ubuntu expertise than me for help.

I have read loads of documentation that tells me to modify the `/etc/fstab` folder with the following line and I have done this using the gedit function as a super user. I have added the following line to `/dev/fstab` to no avail.

```
/mnt/88b11020-8c51-42e6-8525-950eaa23d888/home/myusername/Uncompressed1music Uncompressed\ music        none    bind
```

This just does not work. It does not create a bind of the old `home/username/Uncompressed1music` folder on sdb1 to the `home/Uncompressed music` on my home folder at startup as I would have hoped.

What am I doing wrong? I will gladly send a coconut by mail order to anybody who can help me sort this one out.

Comment: You need to mount the partition at the correct location first, then use the bind-mount. so you will need 2 lines in fstab, one to mount the partition and another to create the bind-mount. Order of lines in fstab is essential, mount partition first, then bind-mount. How to get a coconut in an envelope?

Comment: The problem is you have a space in your mount point. Linux really does not like spaces in file names or directories.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316017/how-do-i-specify-a-label-path-with-spaces-in-etc-fstab

Comment: Thanks Mnook765. I reckon that the old hard drive, sdb1 is mounted. I used the disks app to automatically mount it at boot up and it is listed in /etc/fstab. An icon for it appears on my desktop and this clicks through to the partition in question. Y=Thanks for your response, but I think that I still have my full complement of coconuts. Thanks also to stackoverflow.com. I tried that and it didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses folks. I have found a far more easy way to do what I wanted.

In the 18.04 desktop, there is a files app. If you click on preferences and select the behavior tab, there is a check box that enables you to create symbolic links. Having checked that box, when I right click on the target folder in my old hard drive, I am now able to create a link to that folder. The link appears as a new entitled "link to xxxx" alongside the original xxxx folder. I just cut and past that link to my home folder and renamed it by removing the words "link to" and the "xxxx" folder appears in my home folder on my new SSD drive. I have just tested it and it works so I guess that I get to keep my coconuts.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're mounting your drive in root folder instead of your home? You seem to be using the relative path `"Uncompressed\ music"` instead of absolute path `"/home/<username>/Uncompressed\ music"`

While creating a symlink (as in your own answer) is a good solution it has at least one drawback - checking the mount point properties you'll see... a link, which it really is. You won't see the drive/partition properties. That is unless you go an check it explicitly on the drive.

Adding a mount point in fstab requires (at least) two things:

1. the drive you mount has to be accessible (see comment to your question)
2. the mount point has to be accessible

Ad 1. you just need to add the drive in fstab, which you have done already.

Ad 2. your home folder cannot be encrypted. If it is, it won't be available on boot, so fstab won't be able to mount anything there (in fact it will mount "nothing" there).

You can use an fstab entry even if your home directory is encrypted, though. 
It takes 2 steps:

- Adding `user,noauto,bind` will not mount that mount point at boot, but will make it available for user mount (no need to be root).

  ```
  /mnt/88b11020-8c51-42e6-8525-950eaa23d888/home/myusername/Uncompressed1music /home/<username>/Uncompressed_music        none    user,noauto,bind
  ```
- creating a following entry in a start script (`.profile` would be perfect for that purpose) in your home folder. It will mount this entry on login (and not at boot).

  ```
  mount /home/<username>/Uncompressed_music
  ```

Cheers